# Літера чи буква? Чи може "різа"?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми

СУМ-11 дає такі визначення:

[Літера](http://sum.in.ua/s/litera) - письмовий знак, що позначає звук або сполучення звуків мови; **буква**.

[Буква](http://sum.in.ua/s/Bukva) - письмовий знак, що позначає звук або сполучення звуків мови; **літера**.

І навіть переносне значення у них однакове.

Зустрічаємо ці слова і в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Звідси можна було б зробити висновок, що ми можемо вживати як перше, так і друге слово.

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) також подає ці два слова як синоніми, однак там же вказується про різну етимологію цих слів.

І, можливо, саме тому, що слово "літера" запозичене із давньогрецької мови на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/litera) навіть шукають заміну цього слова. Там, в коментарях до слова "буква", люди сперечалися чи це також запозичене слово чи ні, а ще вони взагалі пропонують замінити слово "літера" на "різа" (однак, це слово має зовсім інше значення в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/riza)).

Але от сайти [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53403/31289.html) (інформація із Словника-довідника з українського літературного слововживання Головащука) та [Як правильно](https://kak-pravilno.net/bukva-chi-litera-yak-pravilno/) пишуть:

> Вживаються паралельно, але сполучаються з іншими словами по-різному.
> Тільки буква вживається в сполуках: **від букви до букви**, **буква закону**,
> **дотримуватися букви інструкції**, **дух і буква заключного акту
> переговорів.**
>
> Цей чоловік був людиною з великої літери.
>
> «А» – перша літера алфавіту.

І тому я можу зробити висновок, що все ж це не абсолютні синоніми, а тому цікавить ситуації в яких можна вживати слова "літера" та "буква" як синоніми,  і чи є ще випадки, коли можна вживати лише якесь одне із цих слів? І чи справді нам краще замінити слово "літера" на "різу"?

Comment: Перефразуючи ваше запитання, воно звучить так: *«в яких контекстах ці слова є / не є синонімами?»* — і відповіді ви самі надали: (1) офіційні словники вказують, що синоніми; **без вказування контексту, значить — в усіх контекстах**. (2) неофіційні сайти пропонують різне вживання **у сталих висловах**, але не надають пруфлінків. Висновок: я не бачу іншої відповіді на ваше запитання, окрім тієї, що вже надана у самому запитанні. Ну, або "unclear what you're asking", і запитання варто уточнити.

Comment: У мене прохання — якщо маєте змогу, намагайтесь указувати найточніші джерела. Наприклад, «Словопедія» — це сайт-агрегатор, що публікує інформацію з багатьох першоджерел, і згори від статті зазвичай видно, з якого саме джерела вона взята (у даному разі «Літературне слововживання» означає «Словник-довідник з українського літературного слововживання» Сергія Івановича Головащука; тобто посилання можна залишити на Словопедію, бо читачу перейти на сайт простіше, ніж вивантажувати doc-файл, але походження цитати варто вточнити).

Comment: А ось «Цей чоловік був людиною з великої літери. „А“ – перша літера алфавіту» — це приписка, яку невідомо звідки взяв сайт «Как правильно» (більше ніде не гуглиться), тобто він до плагіату зі словника Головащука долучив власні погляди.

Comment: Добре, пізніше додам першопочаткові джерела.
На рахунок того, що в питанні вже є відповідь:
1. Там немає відповіді чи можна взагалі вживати слова "різа"
2. Також я запитався в яких випадках слово "буква" не можна замінмти словом "літера", і як бачимо, Олександр вже написав, що "людина з великої літери" - це лише приписка, автора сайту. А тому мене цікавлять конкретні приклади, коли ці слова не будуть синонімами.
3. Чи взагалі варто вживати слово "літера", бо ж на Словотворі цьому слову вже знайшли заміну.